# Replication 2d Matrix x by replicating each item horizontally, vertically and diagonally

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have this code:

```
somearray = np.array([[1,4,7],[8,9,3]])
# i tried this
print(np.tile(somearray,2))
```

i got this result:

```
[[1 4 7 1 4 7]
 [8 9 3 8 9 3]]
```

I try to get this result:

```
1 1 4 4 7 7 
1 1 4 4 7 7 
8 8 9 9 3 3 
8 8 9 9 3 3
```

each item is replicated horizontally, vertically and diagonally, how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with both np.repeat and np.tile. Please Note the differences

```
np.repeat(np.repeat(somearray,2, axis=1),2,axis=0)
```

Output

```
array([[1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7],
       [1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 9, 9, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 9, 9, 3, 3]])
```

Option 2

```
np.tile(somearray,(2,2))
```

Output

```
array([[1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7],
       [8, 9, 3, 8, 9, 3],
       [1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7],
       [8, 9, 3, 8, 9, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are trying to do is called upsampling. You may use the `np.repeat` function:

```py
somearray.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
```